# A/B/C test with unequal sample size distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, python, inference, ab-test

I have A/B/C variant test results with control version A containing 50% of the population and test versions B and C having an equal split of 25% each. How should I interpret my results? Does having an unequal sample size makes any impact on the statistical significance results? I have added Bonferroni corrections to my p-value to capture multi-variant testing. For eg. I am computing Total sales per week, given this is not a proportion-based metric how do I analyze the results outside the p-value metric?
The objective of the experiment is to understand if there is an increase in the total sales per week and understand if the test results can be considered reliable

I'd appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: What is the question your experiment seeks to answer?

Comment: Hello @dimitriy, The objective of the experiment is to understand if there is an increase in the total sales per week and understand if the test results can be considered reliable.

Comment: You can ask many questions here that fall into those two buckets with this test design. Does B have more sales than A? Does C have more sales than A? Do B and C jointly have more sales than A? Is the lift from showing B vs. A greater than showing C vs. A? Are those differences within $K from each other? Are these differences economically significant and statistically significant? Are the experimental group sizes consistent with the test design? Is there any difference in sales, positive or negative? And probably many more, especially if B and C are related in some way.

Comment: @dimitriy Let's assume that I am trying to answer `Does B have more sales than A?` How do I account for the difference is sample sizes in this analysis and for statistically significance calculation? Thanks for giving such a prompt response. Appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have granular, user-level data? Or only totals for each group and week?

Comment: Yes, I do have granular user-level data on a daily level basis for the duration of the experiment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141235/discussion-between-samyak-jain-and-dimitriy).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to test such hypotheses on means (average revenue per user) rather than on the totals (sums of revenue in each group). But both are doable since means and totals are closely related:

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_i^N y_i = \bar y \rightarrow \sum_i^N y_i = N \cdot \bar y$$

Here is a Stata example using a dataset of 48 pigs whose weight is observed over nine weeks. We start by loading the data:

```
. #delimit;
delimiter now ;
. webuse pig, clear;
(Longitudinal analysis of pig weights)

. xtset id week;

Panel variable: id (strongly balanced)
 Time variable: week, 1 to 9
         Delta: 1 unit

. xtdescribe;

      id:  1, 2, ..., 48                                     n =         48
    week:  1, 2, ..., 9                                      T =          9
           Delta(week) = 1 unit
           Span(week)  = 9 periods
           (id*week uniquely identifies each observation)

Distribution of T_i:   min      5%     25%       50%       75%     95%     max
                         9       9       9         9         9       9       9

     Freq.  Percent    Cum. |  Pattern
 ---------------------------+-----------
       48    100.00  100.00 |  111111111
 ---------------------------+-----------
       48    100.00         |  XXXXXXXXX
```

Now we split the pigs into three groups (24 in A and 12 each in B and C):

```
. set seed 12112022;

. splitsample, cluster(id) split(.5 .25 .25) gen(group);

. label define group 1 "A" 2 "B" 3 "C";

. label values group group;
```

We will force the B pigs to gain 10% more weight:

```
. generate gain = D1.weight;
(48 missing values generated)

. replace gain = 1.1*gain if group =="B":group;
(96 real changes made)

. collapse (sum) gain, by(id group);
```

The last step sums up each pig's weight gain over the 9 weeks. This gets us back to 48 observations/rows.

Let's set Group C aside for now, so we only have 36 pigs to work with. We can do the test on totals:

```
. /* (1) Test Two Totals */
> total gain if inlist(group,"A":group,"B":group), over(group);

Total estimation                            Number of obs = 36

--------------------------------------------------------------
             |      Total   Std. err.     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
c.gain@group |
          A  |     1212.5      25.43      1160.874    1264.126
          B  |      657.8   22.59203      611.9357    703.6643
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Though pigs in B grow faster, there are twice as many pigs in A, so the total is ~1.8 bigger.

We can remedy that by scaling the Group B total by 2 as if it had 24 pigs:

```
. test _b[c.gain@1.group] = 2*_b[c.gain@2.group];

 ( 1)  c.gain@1bn.group - 2*c.gain@2.group = 0

       F(  1,    35) =    3.95
            Prob > F =    0.0546
```

This is a two-sided test, but we want the one-sided test that $\Delta \le 0$  against $\Delta > 0$, so we need to divide the p-value by 2: 0.0546/2 = 0.0273. This can be interpreted as saying that if the pigs grew at the same rate and we adjusted for the unequal group size, we would observe a difference like 1212.5-2*657 = -103.1 kg (or even more negative) only 2.7% of the time. Since seeing such a difference would be unusual under the null, we reject the null as false in favor of the alternative that B is better than A.

We can do the same test on the means:

```
. /* Test Two Means */
> ttest gain if inlist(group,"A":group,"B":group), by(group) reverse unpaired unequal;

Two-sample t test with unequal variances
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Group |     Obs        Mean    Std. err.   Std. dev.   [95% conf. interval]
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
       B |      12    54.81667     1.88267    6.521759    50.67294    58.96039
       A |      24    50.52083    1.059583    5.190877    48.32892    52.71275
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
Combined |      36    51.95278    .9901258    5.940755    49.94272    53.96284
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff |            4.295833    2.160361               -.2393633     8.83103
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff = mean(B) - mean(A)                                      t =   1.9885
H0: diff = 0                     Satterthwaite's degrees of freedom =   18.199

    Ha: diff < 0                 Ha: diff != 0                 Ha: diff > 0
 Pr(T < t) = 0.9690         Pr(|T| > |t|) = 0.0620          Pr(T > t) = 0.0310
```

Here we get a one-sided p-value of 0.0310 directly, which is close to what we got with the totals above. These commands make slightly different small sample adjustments, but any differences will be much smaller with a bigger sample.

You can do the same thing with regression:

```
. /* (2) Test Means Using Two-Group Regression */
> regress gain i.group if inlist(group,"A":group,"B":group),  vce(hc2);

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =         36
                                                F(1, 34)          =       3.95
                                                Prob > F          =     0.0549
                                                R-squared         =     0.1195
                                                Root MSE          =     5.6558

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |             Robust HC2
        gain | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       group |
          B  |   4.295833   2.160361     1.99   0.055    -.0945492    8.686216
       _cons |   50.52083   1.059583    47.68   0.000      48.3675    52.67417
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. test _b[2.group] == 0;

 ( 1)  2.group = 0

       F(  1,    34) =    3.95
            Prob > F =    0.0549
```

Again, we need to divide the p-value by 2.

But we can also calculate totals from the regression by multiplying by 24 and 12:

```
. /* (3) Totals From Regression */
> nlcom (A_Total: _b[_cons]*24) (B_Total: (_b[_cons] + _b[2.group])*12), post;

     A_Total: _b[_cons]*24
     B_Total: (_b[_cons] + _b[2.group])*12

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        gain | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     A_Total |     1212.5      25.43    47.68   0.000     1162.658    1262.342
     B_Total |      657.8   22.59203    29.12   0.000     613.5204    702.0796
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. test _b[A_Total] == 2*_b[B_Total];

 ( 1)  A_Total - 2*B_Total = 0

           chi2(  1) =    3.95
         Prob > chi2 =    0.0468
```

This is all to say that you can use regression to test many kinds of hypotheses about more than two groups:

```
. /* (4) Three Group Regression */
> regress gain i.group, vce(hc2);

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =         48
                                                F(2, 45)          =       2.37
                                                Prob > F          =     0.1053
                                                R-squared         =     0.1146
                                                Root MSE          =     5.6343

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |             Robust HC2
        gain | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       group |
          B  |   4.295833   2.160361     1.99   0.053    -.0553579    8.647025
          C  |  -.6041667   1.924946    -0.31   0.755    -4.481208    3.272874
             |
       _cons |   50.52083   1.059583    47.68   0.000     48.38672    52.65494
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. test 2.group;

 ( 1)  2.group = 0

       F(  1,    45) =    3.95
            Prob > F =    0.0529

. test 3.group;

 ( 1)  3.group = 0

       F(  1,    45) =    0.10
            Prob > F =    0.7551

. test 2.group == 3.group;

 ( 1)  2.group - 3.group = 0

       F(  1,    45) =    3.92
            Prob > F =    0.0539

. test 2.group == 3.group == 0;

 ( 1)  2.group - 3.group = 0
 ( 2)  2.group = 0

       F(  2,    45) =    2.37
            Prob > F =    0.1053
```

These are p-values for the two-sided hypotheses that I mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thanks @dimitriy!! What do you think about using bonferroni correction on the p-value given we have multiple variants?

Comment: Assuming you design the test to have adequate power, I would not worry about it with only 3 groups (unless you also have multiple outcomes and/or plan to do many subroup analyses).

Answer (score 0):

> How should I interpret my results?

This depends on the approach used to analyze the data.  Could you say more?

> Does having an unequal sample size makes any impact on the statistical significance results?

This effects the power of the associated test.

Comment: Hello @demetri, The approach I took was to understand how the KPI total sales per week is trending across the duration of the experiment. Given the difference in sample sizes, only directional drops are interpretable. I am not able to quantify the differences in the metric values. Do you have any suggestions here ?


I am using a t-test and taking all records within each variant. Should I sample the control to ensure the same number of records before I do the t-test?